# How to override existing .rar archive?

Tags: rar

How to add *file.txt* to **existing** archive *arch.rar*, but in a way that *arch.rar* will contain only *file.txt* ? I use command like below, but *arch.rar* is updated and contains old files too. I don't see switch to do that.

```
rar a arch.rar file.txt
```

Comment: I know you've said you want to do it within RAR only (comment on deleted answer) but I think it would be simpler to delete the old archive and recreate it so that it just contains the new file.

Comment: There is the "d" command `rar d arch.rar *.*` - but it doesn't look like you can combine commands in one operation.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense ;) but you can do something like this:

```
$ FILE2UPD=file.2; RARCH=arch.rar && for i in `rar l $RARCH | grep -v $FILE2UPD | tail -n +9 | head -n -3 | cut -f2 -d' '`; do rar d $RARCH $i; done && rar u $RARCH $FILE2UPD
```

example:

```
$ cat file.1
test 1
$ cat file.2
test 2
$ cat file.3
test 3
$ rar a arch.rar file.*

RAR 3.93   Copyright (c) 1993-2010 Alexander Roshal   15 Mar 2010
Shareware version         Type RAR -? for help

Evaluation copy. Please register.

Creating archive arch.rar

Adding    file.1                                                      OK 
Adding    file.2                                                      OK 
Adding    file.3                                                      OK 
Done

$ echo "test4" > file.2
$ cat file.2
test4

$ FILE2UPD=file.2; RARCH=arch.rar && for i in `rar l $RARCH | grep -v $FILE2UPD | tail -n +9 | head -n -3 | cut -f2 -d' '`; do rar d $RARCH $i; done && rar u $RARCH $FILE2UPD

RAR 3.93   Copyright (c) 1993-2010 Alexander Roshal   15 Mar 2010
Shareware version         Type RAR -? for help

Deleting from arch.rar
Deleting file.1
Done

RAR 3.93   Copyright (c) 1993-2010 Alexander Roshal   15 Mar 2010
Shareware version         Type RAR -? for help

Deleting from arch.rar
Deleting file.3
Done

RAR 3.93   Copyright (c) 1993-2010 Alexander Roshal   15 Mar 2010
Shareware version         Type RAR -? for help

Evaluation copy. Please register.

Updating archive arch.rar

Updating  file.2                                                      OK 
Done



$ rar l arch.rar 

RAR 3.93   Copyright (c) 1993-2010 Alexander Roshal   15 Mar 2010
Shareware version         Type RAR -? for help

Archive arch.rar

 Name             Size   Packed Ratio  Date   Time     Attr      CRC   Meth Ver
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 file.2              6       16 266% 04-03-11 12:45 -rw-r--r-- 012EC35E m3b 2.9
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                6       16 266%


$ rm file.*
$ rar e arch.rar 

RAR 3.93   Copyright (c) 1993-2010 Alexander Roshal   15 Mar 2010
Shareware version         Type RAR -? for help


Extracting from arch.rar

Extracting  file.2                                                    OK 
All OK
$ cat file.2 
test4
```

Comment: Of course it will fail if archived files have space in name